# How to have a div expand to the height of his sibling div

Tags: html, css, height

I've been searching for a while, but couldn't find a solution.

I have a div containing 2 columns of content.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content1">
    Content1
  </div>

  <div id="content2">
    <span style="font-size: 1500px;"> Stretch height</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#container {
  height: 100%;
}

#content1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  float:right;
  background-color: pink;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#content2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Currently, #content1 has the height of 100% while #content2 was expanded to fit its content.
This way the background color of #content1 appears only at the top and when scrolling down you can see it's not colored.

How can I overcome that? (without using JS)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `min-height: 100%`, you can use `bottom: 0`. When both the `top` and `bottom` attributes are set to 0 it will fill the whole height (if the `position` is set to `absolute`, that is).

Comment: @koela1 ok, if you know which column will be largest, you can do like this: http://jsfiddle.net/niclassahlin/HbSBd/. Otherwise, it is probably better to do it with JavaScript.